# I have a question on empty rules when using CSS

Tags: css

Hi everyone so I am completely new at CSS, trying to learn a thing or two to help out at work. I have a question regarding the bolded section of the code below. It has a warning saying its an empty rule. I want to erase it but I am not sure if the empty rule was left there purposely or? I personally would like to remove it, if its not necessary why have it. If someone can help me out please!

```
}

   **.tophead .col-md-2 {}**                 
   .tophead .col-md-2 i {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #003087;
    vertical-align: super;

}
```

Comment: you can comment it out if you cannot/not sure to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's empty, then it's not changing anything. I'm with the last comment, you can comment it out using /* */ and see if it doesn't change anything in the visuals of the page.

If it doesn't and you are working on someone elses code, I also recommend that you write something in the comments like "Commented out because no rules were applied here".

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting it out if you aren't sure, then look at what happens on the website. You will have to put /* before the code and */ after the code. Here is an example:

```
   /*
   .tophead .col-md-2 {}**
   */                 
   .tophead .col-md-2 i {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #003087;
    vertical-align: super;

}
```

It looks like this code `.tophead .col-md-2 {}` Isn't currently doing anything so it can probably be removed. The other has some styling to it so it may be active on your site. If you comment it out, you should notice a change on your site if it is active.

Comment: Thank you guys! I relayed this to my IT manager and see what happens!

Comment: No problem! Let us know what you find out. =)